# I would like to confirm if the ipv6 subnet is public

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipv6, amazon-vpc

I recently created a AWS VPC with IPV6 CIDR block. The  CIDR block which is allocated to me is 2600:XXXX:XXXX:9500::/56.

I  have some basic knowledge about ipv6 subnet range including ipv6 public and private subnet range.

The subnet starting fd00::/8 is a private network.

Could you please let me know if I was assigned public ip range from ipv6?

To understand the public/ private subnet and ipv6 allocation I have referred following documents :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193 ( To understand the bit allocations in ipv6)

```
  | 7 bits |1|  40 bits   |  16 bits  |          64 bits           |
  +--------+-+------------+-----------+----------------------------+
  | Prefix |L| Global ID  | Subnet ID |        Interface ID        |
  +--------+-+------------+-----------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Anything in the `2000::/3` range (`2000::` to `3fff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`) that is not listed as Global = False in the _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_ is a Global IPv6 address.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your address block is from a prefix allocated by ARIN as you can see on the [IANA website](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments/ipv6-unicast-address-assignments.xhtml). In general prefixes from `2000::/3` are "normal" globally unique anycast addresses, although there are some special cases like `2001:0000::/32` (Teredo) and `2002::/16` (6to4). You can find out about those on the same IANA page.

Whether your block is actually connected to the internet depends on routing, firewalling etc. To find out about that you should contact your network administrator (in this case AWS) or read their documentation.

There is no specific algorithm to determine the address classification, so this question was probably off-topic here and should be moved to ServerFault..

Answer (score 2):

In VPC, the assigned IPv6 supernet block **is always public** and always has a `/56` prefix.  The individual subnets always have a `/64` prefix.

There are no private IPv6 addresses in VPC in precisely the same sense that there are private IPv4 addresses in VPC -- IPv6 in VPC is different.

> IPv6 addresses are globally unique, and are therefore public by default. If you want your instance to be able to access the Internet, but you want to prevent resources on the Internet from initiating communication with your instance, you can use an egress-only Internet gateway.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/egress-only-internet-gateway.html

In IPv6, an egress-only Internet gateway -- in a very loose sense -- serves the same purpose as a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance in IPv4.  Specifically, it allows outbound Internet access for internally-initiated connections and allows correlated inbound responses, while preventing inbound externally-initiated connections from the Internet from reaching the instances in those subnets.

With IPv6 in VPC, the public vs. private subnet designation is only related to the default route of the subnet.  The addresses in both types of subnets will all come from the one single `/56` block of addresses allocated as the VPC supernet.